# OpenLayers SelectedFeature with array of vector

Tags: openlayers, extjs4.2, geoext

I have recently started to work with GeoExt and OpenLayers to generate a web gis application.
During the development of this application i have found a problem using the object 'OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature'.

I have various objects 'OpenLayers.Layer.Vector' that shows on the map a geometric points.
Each point must show a popup with his features's attributes. 
To generates this popup i have use this function:

```
        function createPopup(feature) {
        var popupOpt = Ext.apply({
            title: feature.attributes.title,
            location: feature,
            html: feature.attributes.html,
            collapsible: false,
            unpinnable: false,
            maximizable: true,
            icon: feature.attributes.icon,
            border: false,
            style: {
                borderColor: 'white',
                borderStyle: 'solid'
            }
        });
        popup = Ext.create('GeoExt.window.Popup', popupOpt);
        popup.on({
            close: function() {
                selectCtrl.unselectAll();
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
```

Now, when i create a control object 'OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature' with an array of vector object this don't work, while if i create a control object with only one vector object, this works correctly.

This works correctly:

```
var vectorStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({'pointRadius': 4, 'externalGraphic': 'resources/images/logo.png', 'graphicWidth': 30, 'graphicHeight': 25, 'fillOpacity': 1.0, 'cursor': 'pointer'});
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("StationA",{styleMap: vectorStyle, visibility: false});

var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vector,{onSelect:createPopup});

mapPanel.map.addControls(selectCtrl);

selectCtrl.activate();
```

If i use an array : **...SelectFeature([vector1,vector2,vector3],...** don't work:

```
var vectorStyle = ....
var vector1 = ...
var vector2 = ...
var vector3 = ...

var selectCtrl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([vector1,vector2,vector3],{onSelect:createPopup});

mapPanel.map.addControls(selectCtrl);

selectCtrl.activate();
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: What doesn't work, the feature doesn't get selected, or the popup doesn't get added? SelectFeature is definitely designed to work with multiple layers.

Comment: The vector objects are added to SelectFeature object but, on the map, i can't interact with them. If i load one vector object, on the map, i can interact with point, the mouse cursor change and when i click on any marker the popup is opened, but when i load an array of vector objects nothing happens.

Comment: I take it you have seen this example: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html I would suggest you put a full example up on jsFiddle, as it is hard to debug from code fragments. In my experience with OpenLayers, the error may well be due to an error somewhere else, that prevents some later function from running.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already seen the example that you suggested. I'll try again to resolve the problem. If i don't find the solution i'll put all up on jsFiddle. Thanks again